# What is kondemand?

Tags: process, power-management, thread

I have searched the web for the answer of this question but couldn't find a clear answer. Best answer I found was as follows:

> kondemand is a kernel thread that belongs to the ondemand governor of
>   cpufreq subsystem, which changes the p-states of the system, based on
>   the utilization statistics. Thus it’s something that helps in power
>   management.

But still there is uncertainty about the meaning **in what way kondemand helps power management** or **is it really a process/thread concerning with power management?**

Can someone please explain it?

Answer (score 8):

The `kondemand` process helps conserve power by reducing the CPU-Speed if the CPU isn't needed to run at maximum speed.

Reduced Clock Speed == Reduced power requirements.

Personally, I find that very useful on portable devices (smartphones, netbooks) but I'm not sure about that feature when it comes to Servers.